# strange php reference passing

Tags: php, reference, parameter-passing

there's a function F(). it returns object '$O' which is containing an instance of class 'C'.

$O has a member variable '$O->a'.

$O->a is containing '&$v', a reference of variable $v.

writing in code is like this.

```
function F() {
    $O = new C();
    return $O;
}
```

and, i've called this function from other place, got an instance of C like this.

```
$aO = F();
```

in common sense, $aO->a should have been containing &$v. if $v has value '2', $aO->a must has '&int(2)' when it have been dumped. because it is a reference.

but it doesn't. it is containing value 'int(2)'.

i don't know why it is happening.

when i've dumped the member variable just before return like this,

```
function F() {
    $O = new C();
    var_dump($O);
    return $O;
}
```

$O->a is perfectly normal. it definitely containing '&int(2)'. but it is automatically change it self to value after returning.

why it is happening? help me.

Comment: what's your class definition for C? And where is $v defined?

Comment: Can't tell much without seeing all the code. PHP is not C, just a side note.

Comment: Where am I wrong ? - https://eval.in/960177

Comment: class C is just some collection of member variables. its constructor requires some arguments. $v is passed through constructor. the argument is requires reference passing. so it looks like this C::__constructor(&$arg) and actually passed like this. $O->C(&$v); the constructor put &$arg into $this->a. i've much simplified code for quick understanding, but the logic itself is not much different. important thing is that, $O->a have normally contained &$v before it just has been returned.